# El Capitan made my JVM unattainable

Tags: java, android, macos, jvm

Alright, i dont know if this problem should go here, so please point me somewhere else if i am wrong.

Since i updated my macbook to OSX El Capitan (10.11.2) i have been unable to use my JVM for development. This means that i cannot open eclipse, Android studio, or package any apps.

I read somewhere that they added some kind og security layer, that might be causing this problem. Fixed that with some command line prompts and got my other packages working, but still having trouble with Java.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please be more specific about what problem you have, what java environment you have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple offers a legacy java environment for download at:
https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US

Oracle offers current java for Mac
https://www.java.com/en/

I'd strongly recommend to stay away from the legacy java environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried both of these. The problem is not that the environment is missing, but that i can't use it from my command line, or in my IDE's

Comment: Hi, installed various SDK packages, and environments.
As usual i have overcomplicated the issue and it seemed that just a normal update and a restart was enough. Pretty sure that is was the link for the current environment provided by oracle that you linked, so Ill mark your answer as accepted.
Cheers and have a nice day